# Reading an dynamic Excel File with C# error

Tags: c#, excel, file-io

I am trying to read an excel file with C# and display every cell in the sheet inside a messagebox using the `messagebox.Show()` method. Problem is that my excel file has 5 rows and 3 columns. here is my excel sheet: http://postimg.org/image/xts9n1kif.

It displays everything until "roof" and after that stops leaving behind "light" and "iron", but if i fill the stuff3 column it reads everything perfectly fine. As is my case, the file may change. It may have more columns or rows in it, and some of them may be empty.

Any idea why it is not working?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ReadFromExcell
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\ItemDB.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;


            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                }
            }
            //Close the excel file after reading it.
            xlWorkbook.Close();
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the spreadsheet? Maybe a screenshot.

Comment: Looks OK to me.  Must be your data.

Comment: sorry for the broken link, here is a new one: http://postimg.org/image/xts9n1kif/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely what happens in your code is that when the loop hits cell **C4** (which is empty) `xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2` becomes **null**.

Trying to invoke the *ToString()* method (or any other method, for that matter) on a `null` reference will cause a **NullReferenceException**.

Change your code inside your loop from...

```
MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
```

...to something like that:

```
MessageBox.Show( (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 ?? "<no value>").ToString() );
```

The **[?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)** is handy in this situation. If the expression on the left side of ?? (that is `xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2`) results in a *null* value, the *??* operator returns the value on the right-hand side of *??* instead.

(The cell C4 could contain a number of white-space characters, in which case the cell's value would not be *null*. But a cell with just a number of white-space characters is a rather unusual and rare occurrence.)

Answer (score 0):

Now Try this..

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= xlRange.Rows[0].Columns.Count-1; j++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Same problem, it displays "roof" and stops, by showing up the form.

Comment: can you tell the row count and column count ?

Comment: rowCount = 5 colCount = 3

Comment: alright, because i simply printed in a message box the varialbe values. just a minute

Comment: this is the power of debug .

Comment: @MrEnergy, while debugging, check the value of the `Value2` property of the cells. My suspicion is that cell C4 is still part of the range, but it has a value of `null`. Now, in such a case `Value2.ToString()` would throw an exception, bailing out of your algorithm. (That you don't notice the exception is probably due to it being silently swallowed somewhere else in your code...)

Comment: i = 4 and j = 2 when it reaches "roff" after that steps out from the loop and loads the form..

Comment: @elgonzo yes elgonzo i belive that might be the problem because of the null value in the cell, as if i fill the cells with some values it displays all the content properly.

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui, no, please undo your last edit. Excel Range objects are 1-based, not 0-based.

Comment: @MrEnergy, that is because Shujaat's latest edit just makes the code throw an exception instantly.  :)

Comment: Yes, this line throws and exception that is somewhere silently swallowed : MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString()); , so what could do to if the line is null keep looping